# How can I pass an assertion in Jmeter to validate the parten of my generated random UUID for every iteration?

Tags: jmeter

[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12} this is how my UUID looks like

Comment: Not sure I follow the question - is this a response you are trying to validate or a parameter you are trying to generate?   Can you share jmx?

Comment: any update on this ? if answer is ok you should accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where your generated random UUID comes from but supposing you have put it (through CSV Reader or some extractor) in variable randomUUID and that it's accessible through:

> ${__P(randomUUID)}

use a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in the following configuration:

- Check Matches
- Check JMeter Variable and enter **randomUUID**
- Fill in the correct regexp for your UUID (you will have to create it)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your regular expression does not work, I would try to add capital letters, and make it more generic:

```
[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a UUID in Response when I call a 'GET' Rest Service. And I need to validate it for every iteration.

[Here is what I have tried with Reg Exp and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGwpd.png)

[Response Assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmBxT.png)

For [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}

It kind of works but the problem here is the if i change this [0-9a-f]{8} to [0-9a-f]{7} or any other number <8 its still works fine
Even If i change this [0-9a-f]{12} to [0-9a-f]{10} or any other number <12 its still works fine

Comment: Do you mean "false negative" on validation?

And do you have in the radio "Matches", or "Contains"?